# Domain created, applied to feature class, but pick list not showing in table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, domains

Domain was created, applied to a field in a feature class, but the pick list not showing in the table when I edit the feature class. In ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.

I am wondering what I have missed?

[image]

Comment: Does your feature class contain subtypes? If so, apply domain to the field at the subtype level

Comment: Have you closed ArcCatalog and reopened (to refresh)? Are you sure you are editing that feature? (pick lists don't show otherwise)